# Does bikur cholim apply to a non-Jew?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, mitzvah, choleh-sick

Does visiting non-Jewish sick fulfill the mitzvah? Or is it only for Jews?

Comment: In my understanding of "דְּתָנֵי רַב יוֹסֵף: ״וְהוֹדַעְתָּ לָהֶם״ – זֶה בֵּית חַיֵּיהֶם, ״אֶת הַדֶּרֶךְ״ – זוֹ גְּמִילוּת חֲסָדִים, ״אֲשֶׁר יֵלְכוּ״ – זֶה בִּיקּוּר חוֹלִים, ״בָּהּ״ – זוֹ קְבוּרָה, ״וְאֶת הַמַּעֲשֶׂה״ – זֶה הַדִּין
" https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.30b.11, since the Mitvzah of proper burial applies to the Jews only, Bikur Cholim does also. 
As a rule, all interpersonal Mitzvos in the Torah apply inherently to the Jews, but if the failure to apply those toward Gentiles leads to negative implications, Jews are instructed/advised to do so.

Comment: @AlBerko That's incorrect. Jews are not just instructed to help gentiles if it may lead to negative implications. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One visits gentile patients too because of [דרכי שלום peaceful ways](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88544/759) (Gittin 62b, YD 335:9).

Comment: So it would be a different Mitzvah altogether.

Comment: @AlBerko That's much stronger than I would say. There is certainly plenty of overlap in value.